# Is there a way to create an array using env?

Tags: arrays, bash, environment-variables

I have following task: I need to create output like VAR=VALUE

I have some vars like

```
PLR_DEFAULT_MANIFEST_DIR="./manifests/"
PLR_USE_DEFAULT_MANIFEST_DIR="true"
PLR_PATH_TO_K8S_DIR="./manifests/" 
PLR_OUTPUT_FORMAT="yaml"
PLR_THRESHOLD="50"
```

Since variable are dynamic which means in the future there will be more or less of them, I use following code to gather them from env

```
LIST_PLR_VARIABLES=$( env | grep "PLR" )
```

Unfortunately, they all are stored in 0 cell of array and output is spoiled

Well, How can I fix it?

Comment: `LIST_PLR_VARIABLES=($( env | grep "PLR" ))`

Comment: Ohh, I am sorry I've just forgotten to add (). So stupid 

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is bash expansion that expands to all set variables. And there is bash indirect expansion. You can:

```
PLR_DEFAULT_MANIFEST_DIR="./manifests/"
PLR_USE_DEFAULT_MANIFEST_DIR="true"
PLR_PATH_TO_K8S_DIR="./manifests/" 
PLR_OUTPUT_FORMAT="yaml"
PLR_THRESHOLD="50"

for i in "${!PLR_@}"; do
    printf "%s=%q\n" "$i" "${!i}"
done
# or I think alternatively:
declare -p "${!PLR_@}" | sed 's/.*-- //'
```

From [bash parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> ${!prefix*}
> ${!prefix@}
>
> Expands to the names of variables whose names begin with prefix, separated by the first character of the IFS special variable. When ‘@’
> is used and the expansion appears within double quotes, each variable
> name expands to a separate word.

Comment: Although I have just forgotten to add (). Your answer is really helpful for me as I don't know about this kind of expression. Thank you